# the attachable property 'triggers' was not found in type 'style' wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I can use `<Style.Triggers>`, I got message "the attachable property 'triggers' was not found in type 'style'"? I need to use it, for change background image picture.
Can anyone help me?

```
<Button Content ="A" Name="btmeunu" Width="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="75" Margin="-8,-16,0,-6">
</Button>
```

Comment: How about showing us that style?

Comment: <Style x:Key="Triggers" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
        <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Instead, edit your question.

Comment: Where are you defining that Style? As an attribute of your Button or in some Resources?

Comment: almulo i define after <button>

Answer (score 0):

```
//Convertor
public class BackgroundImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isClicked = (bool)value;
    if(isClicked)
    {
        return new ImageBrush([[image1.png as bitmap]]//Change accordingly)
    }
    return new ImageBrush([[image2.png as bitmap]]//Change accordingly)
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}

//XAML

Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsPressed,Converter={StaticResource BackgroundImageConverter}}"
```

Comment: StaticResource BackgroundImageConverter fail at here

Comment: Please refer Convertor in resources

Comment: sorry, how i can refer Convertor in resources, tks

Comment: now i refered it, but when i  click, this button have color red, i can't see image2, now what do i do ?

Answer (score -1):

Is it windows 8 metro style apps??Triggers aren't supported in Windows 8 Metro style apps.

Comment: if it dont support, so how i can set back ground image for button when it be pressed.

Comment: Use convertor(preferrable) or VisualStateManager

Comment: please give me code, now i have image1.png and image2.png.
<button></button>